# Billiard balls collision

Tags: code-golf, geometry, linear-algebra, physics

Given the 2-dimensional positions and velocities of a pair of billiard balls right before impact, calculate their velocities after a perfectly [elastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision). The balls are assumed to be ideal spheres (or equivalently: circles) with the same radius, same mass, uniform density, and no friction.

Input consists of 8 numbers: `p0x,p0y,v0x,v0y,p1x,p1y,v1x,v1y` where `p0x,p0y` is the centre of the first ball, `v0x,v0y` its velocity, and similarly `p1x,p1y,v1x,v1y` for the second ball. You can accept input in any order and structured in any convenient way, e.g. as a 2x2x2 array, or maybe a 2x2 array for `p` and two length-2 arrays for `v0` and `v1`. It's also fine to take complex numbers (if your language supports them) instead of xy pairs. However, you should not take input in a coordinate system other than Cartesian, i.e. polar is not allowed.

Note that the radius of a billiard ball is half the distance between `p0x,p0y` and `p1x,p1y`, so it's not given as an explicit part of the input.

Write a program or function that outputs or returns 4 numbers in any convenient Cartesian representation: the post-collision values of `v0x,v0y,v1x,v1y`.

[image: collision diagram]

A possible algorithm is:

- find the *normal* line that passes through both centres
- find the *tangent* line that passes through the midpoint between the two centres and is perpendicular to the normal line
- change coordinate system and break down `v0x,v0y` and `v1x,v1y` into their tangential and normal components `v0t,v0n` and `v1t,v1n`
- swap the normal components of `v0` and `v1`, preserving their tangential components
- change back to the original coordinate system

Tests (results rounded to 5 decimal places):

```
   p0x   p0y   v0x   v0y   p1x   p1y   v1x   v1y ->      v0x'       v0y'       v1x'       v1y'
[-34.5,-81.8, 34.7,-76.1, 96.2,-25.2, 59.2,-93.3] [  49.05873, -69.88191,  44.84127, -99.51809]
[ 36.9, 77.7,-13.6,-80.8, -7.4, 34.4, 15.1,-71.8] [   5.57641, -62.05647,  -4.07641, -90.54353]
[-51.0, 17.6, 46.1,-80.1, 68.6, 54.0,-35.1,-73.9] [ -26.48927,-102.19239,  37.48927, -51.80761]
[-21.1,-52.6,-77.7, 91.5, 46.0, 94.1, 83.8, 93.7] [ -48.92598, 154.40834,  55.02598,  30.79166]
[ 91.3, -5.3, 72.6, 89.0, 97.8, 50.5, 36.2, 85.7] [  71.73343,  81.56080,  37.06657,  93.13920]
[-79.9, 54.9, 92.5,-40.7,-20.8,-46.9,-16.4, -0.9] [  47.76727,  36.35232,  28.33273, -77.95232]
[ 29.1, 80.7, 76.9,-85.1,-29.3,-49.5,-29.0,-13.0] [  86.08581, -64.62067, -38.18581, -33.47933]
[ 97.7,-89.0, 72.5, 12.4, 77.8,-88.2, 31.5,-34.0] [  33.42847,  13.97071,  70.57153, -35.57071]
[-22.2, 22.6,-61.3, 87.1, 67.0, 57.6,-15.3,-23.1] [ -58.90816,  88.03850, -17.69184, -24.03850]
[-95.4, 15.0,  5.3, 39.5,-54.7,-28.5, -0.7,  0.8] [  21.80656,  21.85786, -17.20656,  18.44214]
[ 84.0,-26.8,-98.6,-85.6,-90.1, 30.9,-48.1, 37.2] [ -89.76828, -88.52700, -56.93172,  40.12700]
[ 57.8, 90.4, 53.2,-74.1, 76.4,-94.4,-68.1,-69.3] [  51.50525, -57.26181, -66.40525, -86.13819]
[ 92.9, 69.8,-31.3, 72.6,-49.1,-78.8,-62.3,-81.6] [-123.11680, -23.48435,  29.51680,  14.48435]
[-10.3,-84.5,-93.5,-95.6, 35.0, 22.6, 44.8, 75.5] [ -11.12485,  99.15449, -37.57515,-119.25449]
[ -3.9, 55.8,-83.3,  9.1, -2.7,-95.6, 37.7,-47.8] [ -82.84144, -48.75541,  37.24144,  10.05541]
[-76.5,-88.4,-76.7,-49.9, 84.5, 38.0,  4.2, 18.4] [   6.52461,  15.43907, -79.02461, -46.93907]
[ 64.2,-19.3, 67.2, 45.4,-27.1,-28.7, 64.7, -4.3] [  59.66292,  44.62400,  72.23708,  -3.52400]
[  9.8, 70.7,-66.2, 63.0,-58.7, 59.5, 83.7,-10.6] [  68.07646,  84.95469, -50.57646, -32.55469]
[ 62.9, 46.4, 85.0, 87.4, 36.3,-29.0,-63.0,-56.3] [  23.53487, -86.82822,  -1.53487, 117.92822]
[ -5.5, 35.6, 17.6,-54.3, -2.2, 66.8,-15.2, 11.8] [  24.15112,   7.63786, -21.75112, -50.13786]
```

Shortest wins. No loopholes.

---

thanks @Anush for [helping](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52466876#52466876) fix the diagram's background colour

Answer (score 17):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>67</s> <s>66</s> bytes, 53 bytes

```python
def f(p,v,q,w):p-=q;d=((v-w)/p).real*p;return v-d,w+d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVbbUmM5DHxevsKPyeyx17IsX5jiSyiKooYwSxUDmSQEZn@eVcs@7NS@HBKB1VZ3qw/7X6e/X5754@N@9@AeNvvlvPxc3raXe3/18@v91WZz9m/bv/bbcNjdPX3Zfz3sTq@HZ3f298vbn/cfp93xdPvt7rg7uit3fbG59pyDLL5RaIvTz3XxtQRaXC8hLT6JPp10fO4c@GZx187lHqK0yovzpYfWqOsBl3NomVLVau9BqMV@s10Uw3EJfXG1ojtxKIoXgedryIaqTxJF9VXvMTCcBKklEzCSwpWsjZ3PIc5qj0EyCw8MLxSidqna3WVMAAz9u9JQET23eB4YHLph@FRCbj3hVjEF6on1mo7rrDo0bYpHEyMRzkvCBDaN66TsAU@xewZeY0ymXNWBkVvoSXrDhDpobKzDOpEQR9VxDLVTKZMr7QheBc8KJNe6da/oKxF4DG1ck4nhlLXKnPWEUyGlxBbHHLEUAW16HeKe4pyjduih19FnT9A/R2iToIrPUMtTgSo@Tq5c1nlLBSuAZ0msV3CpBeZkTlBCOqpzjtSNDfR11To2Y1/rrBgdqAmTwRFxYDTlsUkzzXMoKRaIwC3QrDKHXDvzypU5avBTMYejhFtXcOVbA0sMheDyiYEWqZmZFLjXWOHdqrxWEszBMJ5WV80TuiTTvJg2rZqvKlAFfvMEtXxSkofmoprHRgV6tBC5if6phzc7NbCa8qhOjC5zAyCbKc/Gj9g@KsdiSuDOcd2PBGsWAQY@Sm1lYKRZpRZyTpQnV802QB2vzPRmOyh4dtsSNaEqpF7FZ@0x5lBma2kJm6pzSKoRc4iqyVQhv9qGUJ0YYh7VjjqNMDKj2k5UeMl37LkvwEBszCzRFZMoCRPq8VRoyK8nZlVNQawRs2qe4FrEjqpKn1sCR2G3G@oaGGyZVoDhCcpQwVJApNw0NkAbQsqqjvKoTj0o2nlLRl0dPMGVY1PIvGBpp9hqlsEVaTak3NBY0093PXeYqaqZhLQDkYYoqnMOz7aDYk5lzOFsY3yC5hPP/K2b16YeCQmb4SCVqoogCE2vUXV68YjquufFsr2Bd/1cjSVFtcmc7hVmz/A3zDJzV8@kXNBYDZm5R@ygJkYcVYsHVOccBec9YauxE9orw80@Vdv2BtcW@BjZvWreQympp/HSKCnDV9AxcY3IRCVHUJ0YrhvXllHFsq8w3CzWXbAryF3L8aG5Q@7jTWE7qEEnuUAP5OeoetbAQHWdw3yVLfWa6dzG26nYbltSTdSyzqFmEs6tDpfqoiSM5Gmtkq5jR3XVXIx309beVNhwNs0xk@0m2RuXPt@DGhUkRGjs9AiPPdeVr6OKkQhVYNxcXDy8HNz@fPv4vH89Le58u3vf776ddvfu8dn99/a/vPjjHG9f7E8IP/XfgYfNl823lx/7p9375n35tXVopR9w8p/H/Wbten15iXz4/Er4vt1uteXstBm97X8QBRhfHn/cfV/R1t/Q52/0NLBvD7vj6xN63D09bQ4vr8/3G7ulbN3VldNh7FZWwpd5tfMc5XNa3ObueNwdTu63tovb/E7N/898/As)

*-1 byte thanks to @ngn*

*-13 bytes thanks to @Neil*

This function `f` takes four complex numbers as input and returns two complex numbers. The ungolfed version is shown in the following.

### Ungolfed

```python
def elastic_collision_complex(p1, v1, p2, v2):
    p12 = p1 - p2
    d = ((v1 - v2) / p12).real * p12
    return v1 - d, v2 + d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVbtTiM5EPzPU/hnsjf2@av9gbRPghBCkL2NlA1REhB7L89VtT0cOumQmDidcZe7qrpnTr@vP1@O6ePjeffD7A6Pl@v@6eHp5XDYX/YvR6x@nQ67980pLOYN/6eIz7i9vTH4O4VovuNqLOIaecb3zeaNEdxl/uQtW3fePR7MN671pvPu@no@Gr3rmenMH@b547q7XB@eHi@7C3Lc3WzubMpOFtuCa4vBui62Focz9OLiYqPgaqRz3ZNL94u5MyZ356XVtBhbumstdGwwObuWQ6yI9u4kNN/vtwswTCquL6ZWZg/JFeB54tnqsqLiGgSotuIcA8OIk1pyIEYEXMlIbGx2fka7d5KTpIFhJTiPLBXZTWYFxMB9pTEi2LfYNDCS64phY3G59chT@ehCjwnHNKnOqGHSBrwwMWLgfomsQKsxPYA94gG7Z@K1xMrAVR0YubkepTdWiEJ9SyjWiDg/oiZ5V3soZXKFjORVeK1EMq1r9sq84omXqI1pMjEMWKspZewwEFKKb37U4UsR0objhNSjn3XUTj1wHFx7pP7ZU5tIVWymWjYUqmL95Mpk1FsqWSF8kphwBBObSymqE0BIZ3TWEbuywbymasam7COegNGJGlkZHeEHRgOPTZpqnl2JvlCE1FyY0ZRcrj2llSt11OCnsg4TIk9dyZVtjSwlKkSXTwymiE3NBOBefaV3K3itQVhHovEQXTWPzBJV86LatKq@qkQV@s0GqmUjSB6aCzT3LRTq0ZxPTXCrpTd7aGQ15hGdGF1mB1A2VT4pP6L9CI5FleCZ/dofkdYsQgwupbYyMOKMhuZyjiFPrpp2ABwPZnrTHhReu3YJTAiF4FWukWPUAWZraZGdijokVs86BGqmUCk/bBMYnRiiHkVGVCOJM6NqT1R6yXb2uS3E4NiYswQtJl4iK8T2WMKQHztmFKYICSNm1TzStRw7UDV8dgkdxd5ujGNgJJ1phRg2UJlQ2BQUKTeMDdLGIaVRE/KITj2C1/06GdE6vJIrk1Qh9YJOO2DDLIOrgNkQc2NiTD/0eu40U4WZJCBDCBiijM46bNIeFHVqYh1GO8ZGaj7x1N/ovDb1iJywmQ6CVFWEg1D1GlGDg3tG1z4vOtsbece6KktA1coM@oq1Z/qbZplzF3tiLkwMQ@bUPXsQE8OPqI4HRmcdhfttYFezJ5Ar0802Vu32RtcW@pize9W8u1Jij@OhUWKmr6hjTNVzJoIcYXRimK5c64wqOvtKoptFswt7hXNX5/jQ3HDu80mhPYhBJ7lQD87PEbUJA4PRtQ71Vdap11TnNp5ORXtbJ9VELWsdMJOk3OpwKRolsiQb1mhAO3ZGV81FeVdt9UnFDk@qOWvS3gz6xA2fz0GMiiAhMLHBljT6HC1fR5QlBUaJcX9z8@PlbE5vD/vj6fWKx/7D7v20e7runs3@aP59@o9Xizf/8KJ3BX7ijeD/X02@bdbV@/J7a4iCBZP@vT9tVsC721uOjs@vgd@32@1AmyCbAasvLMs8g9v/evxrPcj6S/j8ZSTgCR7Ou8vrgWkeD4fN@eX1@LzRGmRrvqOA95OeTUP8Mg/4Ngv9pGOe6fFy2Z2vXzMvZvOVvv9uG69k5/3xuvmyafvxDw)

The computation formula is derived based on the 2D-vector formula on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects).
Since \$m_1=m_2\$, the formula can be simplified to
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l} v_1'=v_1-dv \\ v_2'=v_2+dv\end{array}\right.$$

Let \$x_{12}=x_1-x_2\$ and \$v_{12}=v_1-v_2\$, we have

$$dv=\frac{\langle v_{12}, x_{12}\rangle}{\|x_{12}\|^2}x_{12} = \frac{Re(v_{12}\cdot\overline{x_{12}})}{x_{12}\cdot \overline{x_{12}}}x_{12}=Re\left(\frac{v_{12}\cdot\overline{x_{12}}}{x_{12}\cdot \overline{x_{12}}}\right)x_{12}=Re\left(\frac{v_{12}}{x_{12}}\right)x_{12}$$

In the ungolfed program, `p12`, `v1 - v2`, `d` correspond to \$x_{12}\$, \$y_{12}\$, and \$dv\$, respectively.

Comment: well done! this approach looks different from [Ramillies' perl6 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190859/24908) which also uses complex numbers. you could save a byte if you replace `r=p-q` with `p-=q` and further use `p` instead of `r`, like in [Neil's js answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190837/24908)

Comment: @ngn Thanks. I've updated the answer. The formula looks different partially because in Python the conjugate function `p.conjugate()` is very long so I tried to replaced them with `abs(p)` computations for golfing purpose.

Comment: @ngn, it looks different but it is the same, as Joel correctly notes. I wrote the formula in a form that was good for Perl 6 golfing, and Joel presumably used one that was better for Python. Anyway, I didn't think that anybody else would come up with a solution using complex numbers independently. Good job!

Comment: Nice but if you used the algorithm in the question it would only take 53 bytes...

Comment: @Neil Thanks for your hint. The computation is greatly simplified now.

Comment: I'm really liking all your great solutions and detailed explanations!

Answer (score 11):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>90</s> 88 bytes

```javascript
(m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u=(q-=m)*q+(r-=n)*r,v=o*q+p*r-s*q-t*r)=>[o-(q*=v/u),p-(v*=r/u),s+q,t+v]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVXLbls3EN3nKwivJJlk@Ro@ECjL/kCXgoAIsV0oSCRbVowCRb/dPWcuFbToqpuLq4E4hzPncb8e3g6vXy7H56s7nR8e35@276vv9mTP9tm@2It9tVf7Y7t6cdvv683L/eritqf15mLftmf8fN5c3OvmxV03l/X20@7sVi@b7dsvP9b22a3eNtsLX1/vX@z1/m3//vHpfDGr3dGax705P5ndh93O5eLFuh59twbvzbpWfbRmVJ@sS4KnkcH3kX3eW7MzpgwfpLdsjavD9x4HDphSfC8xNVTH8BJ7GPu9BYbJ1Q9rWmP3mH0FXiCea74oKp5RgOoa7rFgGPHSaonESICrBY2NKz7M6gheSpa8YDiJPqBLQ3dTOAEx8L/aWRGcsy4vGNkPxXCp@tJH4q1C8nGkjGua3GbVsGkHXpwYKfK8JE6g05gRsT3iAXsU4vXMybCrtmCU7keS0TkhBg09Y1gj4sNSNTn4NmKtc1foyL0Kn41Ipg/t3thXAvEyuTFdJobB1lrOBScMiJQaeljmCLUK14brxDxSmHO0QT5wHTxHIv8lkJtEVlwhWy5WsuLC3JUpmLc2boXwWVLGFUzqPuekSsBCBqtzjjR0G@xrmnbsun3UMzAGURMnoyLCgtGxxy5dOS@@plBJQu4@zmrOvrSR821XqqhlP41zmJh468Zdud65pUyGqPKJwRapq5gAPFpo1G7DXlsUzpEpPFRvnCd2Scp5VW56U101ogr15iLZcglLXjgXcB56rOSj@5C74K@O2hyxc6upLNWJMWQ6gLQp81n3I@pH7FiUCd453PyRKM0qxOCrtF4XjDSrsftSUixzV10dAMVjM6OrB4XPoS6BCMEQtMp39FjmwGZb7YlOxRySWuAcAjZzbKQfsomsTgxRjaIjppHMzGjqiUYtuUGfu0oMxsbMElhMgiROiOOpxoV@nJhViCJmRMyN80TVMnbAavzpEiqK3u6sIzCyZlolhotkJlaagiSVjtjg2hhSWjWxLNXJRwx6XpMR1uGTuzJZGVItaNoBG2JZdhWRDal0Nkb6wetlUEwNYpKIDjEiRFmdc7isHhRVauYcRh3jEjmfeKpvOK9PPhITtlBBoKqJMAiVr6VqcPHA6s3nVbO9c@94b7oloOpkBr7i7IX6plhm7uJMKpWNIciSR6AHkRhhqWo8sDrnqDzvIl1NT6BXoZpdaur2TtVW6pjZfeN8@FrTSMtHo6ZCXZHHlFtgJmI5wurEMEN3rRlVNftqpppFuwu9wtzVHF84N8x9finUgwg6KZV8MD@XqssIDFZvc6iuiqZeV5778nWq6m1Nqolab3NATJJLb4tKYZTEkVy8VSPsOFi9cS66d@VWv1R0eFbOOZN6M@oXN/78DiIqosTIxgZH8uJzWL4tVY4UWSXGfm3@/GDMwWzN08p7f1x/xM8jfh7998Pz6rT9dPLX86/HPx4fVnHtnw8Pv10Pl@tK1mv/9Xw8fbafeeIRJx7/e0L@cSKGfx8h5uH/HflyPr2evz36b@ffV3e7O3OPm96bu73R94O@31l2xm0wyV/vfwM) Link includes test suite. Explanation: `q,r` are repurposed as the difference vector between the centres, and `u` is the square of its length. `v` is the difference in the dot products of `o,p` and `s,t` with `q,r`, so `v/u` is the scaling factor for `q,r` that gives the amount of velocity transferred from `o,p` to `s,t`. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: i didn't expect someone would simplify the algorithm so much so quickly, well done! here's a [visualization](https://n9n.gitlab.io/tmp/) of your solution (with Arnauld's improvement)

Comment: @ngn Wrong link?

Comment: @Neil gitlab's pipelines log says it should be there. ctrl+f5? arrows control the red ball. shift accelerates. tested in firefox and chromium. warning: sound.

Comment: @ngn Ah, working now, thanks! (I got a 404 before. Also, I was using a private tab, so I had no sound by default, although I didn't find it intrusive. And I'm useless at Asteroids, otherwise I'd ask for a "shoot" key...)

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <del>75</del> <del>64</del> <del>63</del> 61 bytes

*11 bytes saved by switching from `map` to `for`, dispensing with the need to put things into intermediate variables for the `map` to see.*

*1 byte saved by changing `($^a-$^c)².&{$_/abs}` to `($^a-$^c).&{$_/.conj}`.*

*2 bytes saved thanks to @nwellnhof.*

```perl6
{(.($^b+$^d,{$_/.conj}($^a-$^c)*($b-$d).conj)/2 for *-*,*+*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVbbTlxHEHy2v6LlrKzd5cx4bj2XWIn4hDzkmWiBJSEyBrE4kUX4dlLVc/DL4bjNdE1XVdfh4fj4pb7efZePN/KLvD5v/XZzcXm2ubhenjd/fPJX91//fkHp4DYXV7v9dnPpNtc7K@8@Jbm5f5S92y/7s/3u5fXz@@27n@T34@lJrg6n4@lnuf368O3phB9PwDke/jley7@3T3/J4/H07cvT6f27rcvF6@J69H0RvLfFterjIqP6tLikeIoOvo/s826RrUgZPmhveRFXh@89DhyQUnwvMTVUx/Aaexi7BRCSqx@LtMbmMfsKuEA413wxUDyjAtQ1XGNCiHpttURCJKDVgr7iig9rdQSvJWs2CKfRBzRpaC6F9ycEfq12VhTHFpcnRPbDIFyqvvSReKmQfBwp45aS21oVNu2AixMiRR7XxPvbLDIiqCMcoEchXM@cC0S1CVG6H0lH53wYM/SMUUXVh1mVHHwbsdZJFBqSU@WzEUj6sOaNbTUQLlMX6bpCCChrORecEIioNfQwpwi1KjnDbWIeKcwp2qAWuAyeI1H6EqhLoiKuUCkXKxVxYSVKCqatjZQQPWvKuIGk7nNOZgLQMVidU6RhVLCtNGvYjXnUMyAGQRPnohnChOggsWs3uYuvKVQKkLuPazVnX9rIeSXKvDTJaZxCYuKdG4lyvZOiTHVo7xWCHVI3GwF3tNBo2gZSW1ROkWk5VFe5E5skk7uaLr2ZoxpBlU5zkUq5BIKn3Aq5Q4@VWnQfclf8qqMrR@ykNJVZnRBDV@dTMRM9Gzlqawh@1VTgjcPbXiR6sioh@Kqt1wmR1mrsvpQUyySqm/PhdNAyuq2e8jlsO@A@qAOT8h0t5hSgtdWeuKCYQlMLnEKhZI6NysMxkdUJoWZONMQsmhkUzXah0UVucLtdJQSzYg0QbJYGTZwPx1ONU3mcWKvwQ8zIlVXuRLsyaiBo/LEd9BI3urOOlMiWY5UQLlKVWLkMFKh0ZAU5YzBZVWKZ1alFDHbcwhAbwyeJkmzqmA0s4AANm0yiIhIhlc6@CDxseBm0UYONNKJDjMhNVucULtvqqVk0cwqxTXGJcq9wZmwsXF@1SMzUQu9ApqbK7DOtZlVw78Dqut3VwryTc7w3owigNpdgnTh4obFpkzVpcSaVyr6wYskjcPWQE2FWLRRYnVNUHneRu8xdQKtCG7vUbMc77VppYIb1m9zD15pGmh@JmgodRQ1TboExCGqU1Qkhw3i2XKoWdzXTxmrNlTvCpLXgnnILg55fBls9hJuWSi0YmbPqMmKC1XUKc1SxoOsmcZ8fo2obbem0gta3KWAjzaW3aU8sSOJALr5VI7ZwsLrKrca5yWofJu51Nrk5ka1ktM9r/PHVQz5EjZF9BUfy3G4septVDhRZBcTO3x0ets9iP/ZyJvvbnbzMqvtVzg@LnF/Ks5wO3@XDb4/3fz4e7viPkzx/vNn@d37YvSzy9PbHwvo/55cv/gO6fH79Hw)

---

## Explanation

When the original post said that the input could be complex numbers, it was too hard to resist... So this takes 4 complex numbers (position 1, velocity 1, position 2, velocity 2) and returns the velocities as complex numbers.

The program uses just the same algorithm as described in the OP. However, with complex numbers, that is quite simple. First, let's notice that the complex number \$d = p_1 - p_0\$ points from the first ball to the second. So if we divide all the velocities by it, the normal direction suddenly coincides with the real axis and the tangent direction with the imaginary axis. (This messes up the magnitudes but we don't care.)

Now, we need to switch the normal (i. e. real) parts of the velocities \$v_0/d\$ and \$v_1/d\$, and after that, multiply it by \$d\$ again to make the normal (and the velocities) point in the correct direction (and to unmess the magnitudes). So we need to calculate
$$ \begin{align*} v_0' &= d \left( \Re \frac{v_1}{d} + \mathrm{i} \Im \frac{v_0}{d} \right), \\ v_1' &= d \left( \Re \frac{v_0}{d} + \mathrm{i} \Im \frac{v_1}{d} \right) \end{align*} $$
(where \$\Re\$ = real part, \$\Im\$ = imaginary part). Let's shuffle the first one a bit (using \$\star\$ for complex conjugation):
$$ v_0' = d \left( \Re \frac{v_1}{d} + \mathrm{i} \Im \frac{v_0}{d} \right) = d \left[ \frac 1 2 \left( \frac{v_1}{d} + \frac{v_1^\star}{d^\star} \right) + \frac 1 2 \left( \frac{v_0}{d} - \frac{v_0^\star}{d^\star} \right) \right] =\ = \frac d 2 \left( \frac{v_0 + v_1}{d} - \frac{v_0^\star - v_1^\star}{d^\star} \right) = \frac 1 2 \left( v_0 + v_1 - \frac{d}{d^\star} (v_0^\star - v_1^\star) \right).$$
The result for \$v_1'\$ can be obtained just by switching \$v_0 \leftrightarrow v_1\$. All that does is changing a sign:
$$ v_1' = \frac 1 2 \left[ v_0 + v_1 + \frac{d}{d^\star} \left(v_0^\star - v_1^\star\right) \right]. $$

And that's it. All the program does is just this calculation, golfed a bit.

Comment: very cool!­­­­­

Comment: I don't know much about Perl, but I think you could merge the two conjugate computations into one to save some bytes.

Comment: @Joel — Sadly, I'm pretty sure I can't. The first conjugate is acting on `($^a-$^c)` (and only inside a lambda that normalizes this number), the second acts on `($b-$d)`. So they can't really be reconciled. I could make a function that would just call `.conj`, but that would only add bytes (because I heavily use the `$_` variable, which has the nice property that you can call methods on it without specifying it: `.conj` instead of `$_.conj`).

Comment: @Ramillies Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: How is the δ's magnitude relevant? You're just dividing by δ, switching the real components, and then multiplying by δ again.

Comment: @Neil, I'm sorry, that's very poor wording on my part. I just wanted to use dd* = 1 to get the nice d² in the formula (and using the normalized d was what first occurred to me when I was calculating it). By the way, using δ and writing δ/δ* instead of d² saves one byte, and that's what the program currently does. I've updated the explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the explanation now. By the way, @Joel was able to save 13 bytes from his code just now; I just mention it in case there's something there applicable to your answer.

Comment: `{$_/.conj}($^a-$^c)` saves two bytes.

Comment: A port of Joel's Python 3 answer is 46 bytes: `{$^b-($!=(($b-$^d)/($/=$^a-$^c)).re*$/),$d+$!}`

Comment: @nwellnhof — Thank you very much. However, I don't like just blindly copying other answers, so I won't use the port.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>140</s> 132 bytes

```c
f(m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,a)float*a,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t;{q-=m;r-=n;m=q*q+r*r,n=o*q+p*r-s*q-t*r;q*=n/m;*a++=o-q;n*=r/m;*a++=p-n;*a++=s+q;*a=t+n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBBjqQwDLzzCmukXTUhzpKEkEQob@gH7PYBtcRopCVA4Daat/fYtPYyOxJ2TFyuKueOr/f74zFdZpnlIle5ySJ3ecixnv4u4yFG@aUzvG@Y5qFgysOcNrE1RRSZ00LVKgruYsNDlGETKf@aBzE2TVpwG7JI5d//ivlZ7M1GRTqaPHw85vEtX@r3aSmXUxu@err@7m7Dfh/zdHn5McF335/8IuHnTJEpFoqVYqMoFDvFUacUhrW85YNpdKscDX5zMJW4kqi@UTKc7K2u/3@qa03m0XbKAQatAgDVHtD3SgPEXhlA4yiDi1xHq2wFtlcRwHtGaqt6mm15Fr3qTgbK2hEDeuKs0GnV0o0nJHTMzHji7wPfuI66aJ94q2KFRnPtDDOfKhA1OeRZ4okdzwbLiuTHV9y1pO44e56CEE@kZ4xredbyLhAc4dFH9k@6lKPh3buWdzG8BXa8Heqet8CW/ICJpyJjwJ/dcLqle0v4yAyGFfk12op1ie3pwTM/aMNsnv1gCOzE8kb88u0n)

Basically a port of @Neil's JavaScript answer, but then @ceilingcat shaved off 8 bytes by cleverly reusing `m` and `n` to store temporaries.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>97</s> 92 bytes

```python
m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t=input()
q-=m
r-=n
a=o*q+p*r-s*q-t*r
a/=q*q+r*r
print o-a*q,p-a*r,s+a*q,t+a*r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYw5FsMgDER7TkFpY4k8Q7xQcBi6uDCLLBc5PZHTzPw/xdQvf0p2vZ@QoUCFBgQXcDxyvXkYVcN4KsKYVYrFtKkawss0ZEMqvWKTiQQrHZl1wWQaVEk5mR5mSep9QP@2C2jcZ7uDFtlEttXOoMNqnYhbnlrCX4K3fvwB)

Modified version of Neil's approach.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
_/×ḋ÷²S¥_/ʋ¥N,$+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVS7jhQxEMz3Kya4jLHXdtttt07iB5BIiNBodREJuh8gO11CcBkJBBCeSIhIgHRXJPzF7Y8s/bBnLrTdXVNVXT3v393efrhcbvanz0@/H06/jj/fHB9v9v8ejo@v56sXl7@fnv58Od//eHV9vvs6uZfT@e7b9en7Xu@vdqeP/Pb2cll2y7I4yL7Mk2vRt8M8LYQ@8TEVnw5yXvi98kVFH@VcSN8JPBy4QCAAPc1Trb5Kgas@zxN3Zet3ETzKB4J9IBYfBU@@1wFciT7MU6wepQKbNJTsgyFk1A4GUAYOOgJ4WhFS1LuSDIJbGJAydxgJYccX0Rc5N/CNT8CMOwC/gPSzKjGhynsJXK3tNQmjRsyIj6AWtbJ1u0piAVMmZZiC9DtmQQZASU3OoXsUUUxyYVOQSAS0UcBH4ZNppaAmO/5qHAWsUMwNqwbV6AbNqiJca2OSVUnExJMRFVEpQd4AXEqiLHUTsconikzFTEQ1qdVOgScpHBOIyx2BigjjF6XgioUntSFDW4BsDKyfX8MWhJZVVEKLiqMgpkAYNjpqlqViDF1uWlBFokEUVc2NKrKaz7SmsYDGt@auARXAIW1x5lmx03xjHDJZ2prQVBKgNtTuksOkNvAC4WpDDHaXTSgnNnRfuw5Q86nryFlI1yIudQTQQJVOIqmNWm4AnGD@AJkKsMHn@mylWHmx6asRTbcc2tgpea8WMI1sFluiFHcA1BsXyTbCpao28CSrIXA6uCAXw0cbdH5mo0oaeS5N3ssaZ4e6RAgWFJYj7Wzb6iHqGHiFct85zRoNAU0t5SxmGwJocgpuBHiZRfKIikYbcUxRfjbSkLs@jqw4YH@l3eE/)

A dyadic link taking as its left argument a list of the initial positions `[[p0x, p0y], [p1x, p1y]]` and its right argument the initial velocities `[[v0x, v0y], [v1x, v2y]]`. Returns a list of the final velocities `[[v0x', v0y'], [v1x', v2y']]`

Based on the algorithm used by [@Neil’s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190837/42248) so be sure to upvote that one too!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>77</s> 72 bytes

```c
f(p,v,q,w,a)_Complex*a,p,v,q,w;{p-=q;p*=creal((v-w)/p);*a=v-p;a[1]=w+p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY9RasMwDIbfdwpRGNiurc1xEjeYPO0YXRkiNCXQpG4ZyaD07JlrJzvBQA/Sh/j1qVGnppnnlnk5yqucJPGvj0vvz8cfQXKB7u5VfXVe1M3tSGfGRjXxN8@doHpU3tFeH@pp691j7qkbGL@/AKwxQPvs4AJomTI5FrDVnVA7jTsJEIBNwJaoA6hKzBLICswCKKoVVAaNBAL@DPO3bvhuGWxeW1jrc9hISIaCeGi7nk5LG@nT84/HIYWFHFNiFc@AtWglKG2wXFTfo6qymKeNIJ0HoAvUi3t85v/NHvMv)

Based on the python implementation of @Joel

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 bytes

```apl
⊢/-{,∘-⍨×/(9○÷⍨)\-⌿⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVXBih1HDLzPV/TNCWTbrVarW51vycU42NlkYYN3L8H4lGDstZ9JDsY5GwK@7SUmYAiG9Z/Mj2yq1G9zefNGM62SVKWaBz@fnXz/y4Oz88cnD88eXFycPrzd37w9Pd@f/15u96v390@efrO/@PNkP3z48u7@V3N/9@rLP7j5@ruT/fXn/fDx2e1jvLsf3uxXv95c6/78D5y/ePIQv5c/nF7cPsLTp3hcku2Ht/uLq5lEkBGJbj48TjXV/fB3@VH2q7/2w8v99b8tIsy8Xa6zH/eX75/g76P98Olb5A28T4g/2V/9du/8p3vPNiC3bOnm2iV7SrgZuBk9S0qz54qbargkm3EzNWu6TKnNXMyHJsT6zO4ycSK1lr1JHQzPmU28zC1pzzOlMSK3aO7EK8QDVG4Bi18xoCLCSgCRLNvoTQKiAq435MVNy@UuPku2pqbowyQX5BjInlqPTMDAW90ZMpxCSI8Yioou2VzPzWeNwkrNMqui1KTjGE6R2AEowKgSp61GC9FQmoL5ERHosxHQla1hUiMgmudZbTobRJ/FtbE5y2VFk5Y8pvS@MVdM1HgZREk@I/FgSiuEUtKS3CJ9wrSGasP7CRRaL15W/aV347xQh@isBeWPSR5QBH5nDdpbCVIq2cAdicIkOum4uS4xpNTQZx8cBrHVqgI/Vc@qdSkAk5gMb6nOmACzprGy@Ro5nighZuDWGXRADIUQjvG5@eK65V5Lj9mrZ7mLq@Y2purGabDoNZrBRpJUljxGtOHOCakEkrYFwePVQ0JAnaMMCnZgpEMsulAKDmESXZmhLp57sOIjxDSIaSMeiEVLFRMOpg1MF5dOLjwXdSvMS01O8RhpbSsOjGlH0ZfQOiB0zcbWEmLAtlhgzWUtRaUYuxGCf214P0LUY1g8t1albcmX5CFxDmX62juLy4zV0BIMQaESmqnRBuY6utdYT/RhdZTow8CnyiD5kI0wvHEUFHthL6bhESO2YFBEAGpx6R4i6HPZB3bKitXoDxlqlyP3OHQXhyZE4SsbtQrF0mbIkvy/HKGmWGePR3AJXVbW0yWGQmKkexSP/81hFRwcjSnCSdqKblz/dXjZIbYmLpxW0uAo1BAOB3hIJWYlcITanGnhd1jwNkNKA1IysXgDzsn4xngsoC2V0kpxLEfnNTg/4i19txGc481KV20hIHA1zOh@QdgKJxRfGN3Cu20R15aTjzUnAEdvCTvF1hsVTrGE1@JQbZ1ZIcims8T6wTDKCi9vYHxLvQXNQi65EMjTLNDqWKvulGynjMOuF@Uz915nXV@JXhtFRR6rjuJh7MoiKKo0Y8jLm3r4XdcQs0Vq46LQZ5dvk@7weX4XYvtgcdZ6UEHTXGEAwCsYRw8hqRZG50Gvry9RXyu97OkOtK8WoCHT5uOoTqxIrVG43MUFizgZ3sLFLbTTj5@l2GxdZLOjtZcSn1c5fvTgD2IiTJtwRo/7jV0fKxwNCeP/AQ)

based on [@Joel's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190860/24908)

in: 2x2 complex matrix, out: complex pair